# Instagram post's video link from share url

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I'm making an android app that fetches the intagram post details from the post's share url. 
For eg. for getting this https://www.instagram.com/p/Bjzikp0nQG0 post details I'm using Instagram api https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=https://www.instagram.com/p/Bjzikp0nQG0 to get the post details.

But if the post is video I'm only getting thumbnail. I searched a bit and found instagram deprecated the media endpoint. So I found instagram graph api's media endpoint https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/#metadata can be used to get the information.

But the final problem is this above graph api require a numeric id of the post to get the details and nowhere in the documentation mentioned how to convert instagram post's share link to post id.

Comment: So the media_id you get returned in the data from the oembed endpoint is not it …?

Comment: @CBroe I checked that as well but when I make call I get this error (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 1797932728639619508_2533952698 with OAuthException

Comment: Well then you probably don’t have the right permissions to access this piece of content in the first place.

Comment: I'm using the access_token from my developer account.

Comment: Yeah! I just found that my access_token doesn't have instagram_basic permission. 
How can I generate access_token (development) with instagram_basic permission.

Comment: Implement the login flow, or use Graph API Explorer …

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173455/discussion-between-ravindra-barthwal-and-cbroe).